# How to test a sudoku solver?

Tags: computer-puzzle, sudoku

I have created a standard sudoku solver using my own algorithm. It relies on a continuous scanning with occasional tuple/pair searching. I am looking forward to test if this works properly. I have hand tested it one some [Evil](https://www.websudoku.com/?level=4) puzzles.

Is there any source where I can get extremely hard standard sudoku puzzle's (having a unique solution) to test out my solver?

Comment: You may be able to find a suitable open-source sudoku generator.

Comment: https://projecteuler.net/problem=96

Comment: Do the puzzles have to be extremely hard? As far as I know (I never tried), it is possible to enumerate sudoku arrangements by backtracking, and then you can add clues from that arrangement onto an empty grid in random places until a different sudoku solver reports an unique solution.

Comment: well by extremely hard I meant where there are less clues, to check if I missed any logic, as I didn't use backtracking and was trying something on my own. I tried to simulate human solving techniques like using pencil marks, finding naked singles, finding full house/last digit, finding hidden pair etc.

Comment: Is this really classified as a puzzle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to the [Project Euler Problem 96](https://projecteuler.net/problem=96) that Dr Xorile has linked in their comment:

- [Test cases from the Sudopedia](http://sudopedia.enjoysudoku.com/Test_Cases.html), including a list of invalid inputs
- [Benchmark cases](https://github.com/t-dillon/tdoku/blob/master/benchmarks/README.md) used by the developers of Tdoku
  (from [this answer on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60023519))